# Convergence of Projection

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading through the method of Galerkin Approximation for second order parabolic problems in Evans. In particular, there is a regularity estimate he proves (Theorem 5(i) - Section 7.1.3) for which I am unsure of a particular detail. Skipping some earlier details we arrive at two inequalities,
$$\int_{0}^{T}\|\textbf{u}'_{m}\|_{L^{2}(U)}\,dt + \sup_{0\leq t\leq T}A[\textbf{u}_{m},\textbf{u}_{m}]\leq C(\|g\|_{H^{1}_{0}(U)}^{2}+\|\textbf{f}\|_{L^{2}((0,T),L^{2}(U))}),$$
and,
$$\sup_{0\leq t\leq T}\|\textbf{u}_{m}\|_{H^{1}_{0}(U)}^{2}\leq C(\|g\|_{H^{1}_{0}(U)}^{2}+\|\textbf{f}\|_{L^{2}((0,T),L^{2}(U))}).$$
At this point Evans passes to the limit, $m=m_{l}\to\infty$ and concludes that $\textbf{u}\in L^{\infty}((0,T),H^{1}_{0}(U))$ and $\textbf{u}'\in L^{2}((0,T),L^{2}(U))$.

Prior to this Theorem we showed that there exists a unique weak solution of the parabolic problem by using Galerkin Approximation and in particular for the finite dimensional systems that approximate the original parabolic problem we have a subsequences $\{\textbf{u}_{m_{l}}\}$, $\{\textbf{u}'_{m_{l}}\}$ such that $\textbf{u}_{m_{l}}\rightharpoonup \textbf{u}$ in $L^{2}((0,T),H^{1}_{0}(U))$ and $\textbf{u}'_{m_{l}}\rightharpoonup \textbf{u}'$ in $L^{2}((0,T),H^{-1}(U))$. So how are we able to pass to the limit and obtain a result in norm in the above proof if all we have is weak convergence?

I am looking at this proof in particular as I am interested in a perturbed parabolic problem and trying to derive a uniform estimate of the family of perturbed solutions in $L^{2}((0,T),H^{1}_{0}(U))$ and a uniform estimate for the family's respective time derivatives in $L^{2}((0,T),H^{-1}(U))$. In particular, does the estimate that Evans gives in Theorem 2 on page 354,
$$\max_{0\leq t\leq T}\|\textbf{u}_{m}\|_{L^{2}(U)}+\|\textbf{u}_{m}\|_{L^{2}((0,T),H^{1}_{0}(U))}+\|\textbf{u}'_{m}\|_{L^{2}((0,T),H^{-1}(U))}\leq C(\|\textbf{f}\|_{L^{2}((0,T),L^{2}(U))}+\|g\|_{L^{2}(U)}),$$
extend to the eventual solution of the parabolic problem in question?
That is if $\textbf{u}$ is the weak limit as above (and hence the weak solution of the respective parabolic problem) will $\textbf{u}$ satisfy the last inequality above?